# Syntax highlighting thinks entire code block is string

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17817220/866022)'s second code block, there is a string assigned like this:

```
string xmlpath = @"C:\Users\Rick\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Server\server.config\DC_Finalized\" + cboNetGuid.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".xml";
```

The rest of the code block after this is highlighted as though it is one long string (it treats any text that actually *is* a string as non-string plaintext).

It looks like the `@` makes the highlighter treat it as a multi-line literal, and the string ending with a `\` escapes the closing quote, causing the highlighter to treat the entire thing as a string.